# Create a label dynamiclay in form by calling a method from a different class

Tags: c#

As the title implements, how can I call method that adds a control in a form say Form1. I want to call the method and inside that creates several controls like a textbox or labels in the Form that called it

Comment: Possible please post some sample code and expected output.

Comment: The class needs references to the instances of the Form that are actually being displayed.  Which form is the startup form?  Which form or who/where is creating the instance of your class?  Should this method be a member of the Form, or the Class?  So many unknowns here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare controls in a static class and use it both of your forms as follows

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(MyControls.AddLabel());
    }
}

public static class MyControls
{
    public static Control AddLabel()
    {
        Label label = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            Location = new Point(48, 47),
            Name = "label1",
            Size = new Size(46, 17),
            TabIndex = 1,
            Text = "label1"
        };
        return label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've instantiated the second form from your first form, before you call form2.Show(), you can access public properties and functions.

So, either make your label control public, and access it's .Text property, or implement a public method that takes a string parameter, and within that method, assign the string to your label.Text property.

As mentioned, you should post the code you've already tried so people have a better chance of helping you!